# Turk Fair: Meaning?

Tags: meaning, expressions, offensive-language

I was recently told that a term, which seemed to sound like 'Turk Fair' - used in the past - to describe something chaotic. I can only imagine that it relates to the chaos surrounding a street market. The information I have so far is the following:

**Turk Fair**

**Turk** (n.)c. 1300, from French Turc, from Medieval Latin Turcus, from Byzantine Greek Tourkos, Persian turk, a national name, of unknown origin. Said to mean "strength" in Turkish. Compare Chinese tu-kin, recorded from c. 177 B.C.E. as the name of a people living south of the Altai Mountains (identified by some with the Huns). In Persian, turk, in addition to the national name, also could mean "a beautiful youth," "a barbarian," "a robber."

In English, the Ottoman sultan was the Grand Turk (late 15c.), and the Turk was used collectively for the Turkish people or for Ottoman power (late 15c.). From 14c. and especially 16c.-18c. Turk could mean "a Muslim," reflecting the Turkish political power's status in the Western mind as the Muslim nation par excellence. Hence Turkery "Islam" (1580s); turn Turk "convert to Islam."

Meaning "person of Irish descent" is first recorded 1914 in U.S., apparently originating among Irish-Americans; of unknown origin (Irish torc "boar, hog" has been suggested). Young Turk (1908) was a member of an early 20c. political group in the Ottoman Empire that sought rejuvenation of the Turkish nation. Turkish bath is attested from 1640s; Turkish delight from 1877.

**fair** (adv.)Old English fægere "beautifully," from fæger "beautiful" (see fair (adj.)). From c. 1300 as "honorably;" mid-14c. as "correctly; direct;" from 1510s as "clearly." Fair and square is from c. 1600. Fair-to-middling is from 1829, of livestock markets.

Related entries & more
fair (n.)"a stated market in a town or city; a regular meeting to buy, sell, or trade," early 14c., from Anglo-French feyre (late 13c.), from Old French feire, faire "fair, market; feast day," from Vulgar Latin *feria "holiday, market fair," from Latin feriae "religious festivals, holidays," related to festus "solemn, festive, joyous" (see feast (n.)).
Related entries & more

fair (adj.)
Old English fæger "pleasing to the sight (of persons and body features, also of objects, places, etc.); beautiful, handsome, attractive," of weather, "bright, clear, pleasant; not rainy," also in late Old English "morally good," from Proto-Germanic *fagraz (source also of Old Saxon fagar, Old Norse fagr, Swedish fager, Old High German fagar "beautiful," Gothic fagrs "fit"), perhaps from PIE *pek- (1) "to make pretty" (source also of Lithuanian puošiu "I decorate").

The meaning in reference to weather preserves the oldest sense "suitable, agreeable" (opposed to foul (adj.)). Of the main modern senses of the word, that of "light of complexion or color of hair and eyes, not dusky or sallow" (of persons) is from c. 1200, faire, contrasted to browne and reflecting tastes in beauty. From early 13c. as "according with propriety; according with justice," hence "equitable, impartial, just, free from bias" (mid-14c.).

Of wind, "not excessive; favorable for a ship's passage," from late 14c. Of handwriting from 1690s. From c. 1300 as "promising good fortune, auspicious." Also from c. 1300 as "above average, considerable, sizable." From 1860 as "comparatively good."

The sporting senses (fair ball, fair catch, etc.) began to appear in 1856. Fair play is from 1590s but not originally in sports (earlier it meant "pleasant amusement," c. 1300, and foul play was "sinful amusement"). Fair-haired in the figurative sense of "darling, favorite" is from 1909. First record of fair-weather friends is from 1736 (in a letter from Pope published that year, written in 1730). The fair sex "women" is from 1660s, from the "beautiful" sense (fair as a noun meaning "a woman" is from early 15c.). Fair game "legitimate target" is from 1776, from hunting.

Others, who have not gone to such a height of audacious wickedness, have yet considered common prostitutes as fair game, which they might pursue without restraint. ["Advice from a Father to a Son, Just Entered into the Army and about to Go Abroad into Action," London, 1776]

https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=turk+fair

Comment: *"seemed to sound like 'Turk Fair'"*  Where did you hear this?  You seem to have done a lot of research but you give no evidence that you heard it correctly.  What was the complete sentence in which you heard it?

Comment: How sure are you that this isn't an [eggcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn)? The closest word I can think of off the top of my head is "turmoil".

Comment: My elder brother told me that my father used the term once. I do not remember hearing  the term, but I was eager to put it on this site. There may have been more to the term than I was told, or my brother recalls. Hence, 'sounded like...' We would have been quite young at the time

Comment: Apparently we had friends around - creating havoc - when my father arrived back from work. My brother was quite specific. @ njuffa. Definitely, not Eggcorn, The expression, I'm guessing, may have been '..it's like a Turk Fair in here.....with a bit of his inimical 'for pete's sake!'

Comment: This may be an expression used in contempt of foreigners. When I was in grammar school I had a teacher who, when we made a disorderly walk to buses (when it was supposed to be an orderly procession), would say we were "running around like a Chinese fire drill." Only when I got older did I realize this was a fairly racist thing to say.

Comment: We were a 'diverse mix at the time. Interesting?

Comment: @Huggy Any chance it could have been a translated idiom from a language other than English?

Comment: @njuffa. Can't be certain. I found it quite interesting when I saw.an entry, above, for the original 'Young Turks' . I thought that group included the likes of Lord Gray, Winston Churchill, Kitchener, etc   a political group from the pre-first world war era.

Comment: I checked the OED and DARE. I checked dictionaries of Australian, New Zealand, South African, and Canadian variants of English. I checked the SND and all my (UK+US) slang dictionaries. I checked Google Books. I found nothing that fits the bill.

Comment: @njuffa. That's an amazing list of sources. It looks like I will have to subject my brother to some memory jogging techniques. His memory regarding our childhood is far greater than that of mine, I have no doubt he believes what he heard...btw thanks for the word 'Eggcorn'